# Trying to append a file to a tarball through a pipe

Tags: tar, gunzip

I am trying to execute a simple pipeline which should gunzip a file and send the result to stdout. This is ten piped into a tar command which to my knowledge should append the file I specify. I use a hyphen to denote the stdin decompressed tarball which I am trying to append to.

```
gunzip -c sandbox.tgz | tar rvf - hongkong.mp4
```

I receive the following response when I execute the command

```
tar: Options '-Aru' are incompatible with '-f -'
```

Comment: If I read that correctly, you are trying to append the file hongkong.mp4 to a pipe’s stream.  What do you expect as the result?  Tar can’t modify an input stream like it is a file.  (Nor can it create it or concatenation it as a file)

Comment: Ah I didn't realise this.